# Exposing Ports on Android with React-Native

Tags: wi-fi

I'm trying to serve files from a React-Native app. Im using react-native-tcp module but when I create a TCP server it isn't on a nmap output over the mobile device ip address. I've tried with an external client with nodejs but I get ECONNREFUSED. At the same time, If I try with a client inside the react-native app and an external server, I get the same result.

I don't know if there's a protection or the module doesn't work properly. I've also the android.permission.INTERNET in the manifest.

Also with curl command:
[image: That works]

[image: That doesn't work]